# How to press a button with java-script event inside a web-page by code for iOS (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am writing an application for iOS (iPhone).

How to press a button with java-script event inside a web-page? I need to write a code to press this button. Then the event will be executed. And I'll take result of it's work.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById('id-of-button').click();
```

This will perform a click event on the button.

EDIT: to run JavaScript in a UIWebView use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:` method. Eg:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:@"document.getElementById('id-of-button').click();"];
```

Comment: Update: `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('id-of-button').click();"];`